# in python How to get rid of dist files when pip installing with --target --upgrade?

Tags: python, pip

I am in the situation where I have to install a (self made) python package in a folder.
I am using the command:

```
pip install -r $REQUIREMENTS_FILE --target $PROJECT_SHARED_FOLDER --no-deps --upgrade
```

where requirements file is a simply requirements.txt file and the $PROJECT_SHARED_FOLDER is the place for the module to installed.

everytime this is done pip creates a dist file like you can see in the figure

```
name_module-0-1.9.dist-info
```

next time a new version is available a new dist file will be created

```
name_module-0-1.10.dist-info
```

But the old one will remain there!!!
Is there any option in pip to tell pip to delete OLD dist files for a particular module?

thanks
[image]

Comment: `pip install --target` is a hack and with such a hack you're on your own. That is, you need to remove older `*.dist-info` manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is a hack"!?

Comment: You cannot import from the target directory without messing with `sys.path`. You cannot uninstall with `pip uninstall --target`. It's almost not supported and most probably not intended for `pip install --target --upgrade`